# Autocropping, Homemade GPS Tracking

Tags: php, jquery, image, gps, photoshop-script

I have this image:
[image]

I would like to automatically crop anything outside the blue rectangle.

Why?

I plan on using this image w/ some gps gear we have out in the field.  I have instructions not to use google maps/earth.  Using a div with dimensions equal to the pixels of the image, I will set the background image of the div to the picture.  Then using gps data from our database, draw a point and label  within the div.

The corner of the blue boxes indicate the exact coordinates labeled.  So everything outside the blue box is not needed and would through off my points to draw.

Wondering if there is something I can add to me image upload script to auto crop the image.

Or if in reading this anyone decides that I'm being stupid and taking a difficult route, please call me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the uploaded images have same size ?

Comment: If not, the distance between the blue line and the limit of image on Top, left, bottom and right are proportional to each uploaded image size ? Tell more about all constant measures, sameness on each uploaded images. Sorry for english ^^

Comment: Or you can use css property : `#yourDiv{background-image: src("/yourImage.jpg") ; background-postion:-5px -3px }` to fit the image on your div whitout crop it